# Overwrite Databricks Dependency

Tags: maven, databricks, azure-databricks

In our project we're using com.typesafe:config in version 1.3.4. According to the latest [release notes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/6.2.html#installed-java-and-scala-libraries-scala-211-cluster-version), this dependency is already provided by Databricks on the cluster, but in a very old version (1.2.1). 
How can I overwrite the provided dependency with our own version?

We use maven, in our dependencies I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Our created jar file should therefore contain the newer version.

I created a Job by uploading the jar file. The Job fails because it can't find a method that was added after version 1.2.1, so it looks like the library we provided gets overwritten by the older version on the cluster.

Comment: Without knowing better is the Databricks dependency also defined in pom.xml? Or is it a dependency provided byt the deployment environment?

Comment: No, it's not defined in our pom.xml. A lot of libraries are pre-installed on the deployment environment according to which version of the Databricks runtime version you choose.

Comment: @pgruetter did you ever fix this? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: @OscarBonilla: Yes, forgot to update. We did fix it, see my new answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved it in the end by utilizing Sparks ChildFirstURLClassLoader. The project is open source so you can check it out yourself [here](https://github.com/smart-data-lake/smart-data-lake/blob/9ec323e9d16a2616312811c4938db311c3e679c4/src/main/scala/io/smartdatalake/app/AppUtil.scala#L81) and the usage of the method [here](https://github.com/smart-data-lake/smart-data-lake/blob/9ec323e9d16a2616312811c4938db311c3e679c4/src/main/scala/io/smartdatalake/app/DatabricksSmartDataLakeBuilder.scala#L49).

But for reference, here is the method in its entirety. You need to provide a Seq of jars that you want to override with your own, in our case it's the typesafe config.

```
def getChildFirstClassLoader(jars: Seq[String]): ChildFirstURLClassLoader = {
  val initialLoader = getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader]

  @tailrec
  def collectUrls(clazz: ClassLoader, acc: Map[String, URL]): Map[String, URL] = {

    val urlsAcc: Map[String, URL] = acc++
      // add urls on this level to accumulator
      clazz.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs
      .map( url => (url.getFile.split(Environment.defaultPathSeparator).last, url))
      .filter{ case (name, url) => jars.contains(name)}
      .toMap

    // check if any jars without URL are left
    val jarMissing = jars.exists(jar => urlsAcc.get(jar).isEmpty)
    // return accumulated if there is no parent left or no jars are missing anymore
    if (clazz.getParent == null || !jarMissing) urlsAcc else collectUrls(clazz.getParent, urlsAcc)
  }

  // search classpath hierarchy until all jars are found or we have reached the top
  val urlsMap = collectUrls(initialLoader, Map())

  // check if everything found
  val jarsNotFound = jars.filter( jar => urlsMap.get(jar).isEmpty)
  if (jarsNotFound.nonEmpty) {
    logger.info(s"""available jars are ${initialLoader.getURLs.mkString(", ")} (not including parent classpaths)""")
    throw ConfigurationException(s"""jars ${jarsNotFound.mkString(", ")} not found in parent class loaders classpath. Cannot initialize ChildFirstURLClassLoader.""")
  }
  // create child-first classloader
  new ChildFirstURLClassLoader(urlsMap.values.toArray, initialLoader)
}
```

As you can see, it also has some logic to abort if the jar files you specified do not exist in the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

In the end we have fixed this by shading the relevant classes, by adding the following to our build.sbt

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.typesafe.config.**" -> "shadedSparkConfigForSpark.@1").inAll
)
```

Comment: Although this assumes a fat jar is OK

Answer (score 0):

Databricks supports the initialization script (cluster scope or global scope) so that you can install/remove any dependency. The details are at https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html.

In your initialization script, you can remove the default jar file locates at databricks driver/executor classpath `/databricks/jars/` and add the expected one there.